# BIND9 Sharing some domain records across views for a same domain

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

I have a design problem in my BIND configuration. I have 2 views with the same zone `caen2018.com` (splitted for 2 different LANs: CAEN & PARIS).

[image: topology representation]

In each zone I have DDNS record, but I want my DDNS record to be shared between CAEN LAN and PARIS LAN. So, I could do only 1 view for CAEN and PARIS, instead?

But I couldn't because I have specific records depending of the LAN

- the sip one (for the Asterisk).

  - who is a `CNAME` of `SRVCAEN` on Caen and a `CNAME` of `SRVPARIS` in Paris
  - the ISP `A` record is pointing to the closet ISP interface depending of the site `152.36.2.1` on CAEN, and `152.36.2.5` on PARIS.

So the question is how I can do to **shared DDNS records between sites** but **keep specific DNS record of the site** (sip `CNAME` record, ISP `A` record) for a same domain ?

For now, I have the following
in `named.conf.local`:

```
[...]
view "caen-lan" {
   match-clients { "caen-lan"; };
   zone "caen2018.com" {
      type master;
      file "/var/cache/bind/db.caen2018.com.clan";
   };
};

view "paris-lan" {
   match-clients { "paris-lan" };
   zone "caen2018.com" {
      type master;
      file "/var/cache/bind/db.caen2018.com.plan";
   };
};
[...]
```

Comment: "but I want my DDNS record to be shared between CAEN LAN and PARIS LAN" Then you can't use separate views. You seem to have contradictory constraints so you need to change your problem space.